# Scatter Plot with Conditions

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I have a data frame

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
score = [2,4,6]
```

I want to create a scatter plot with the following conditions, color the bubble as green if the score is greater than 3  and red otherwise. I'd also like to label the bubble with its respective name.

I'm only able to create a scatter plot with the bubble having the respective name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to create a list of the colors for every `score` and use the `c` parameter of `scatter()` to set the color inside the plot.

To lable the bubbles you can use `annotate()` on the axis, see an example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
score = [2,4,6] 

# Set color for every score
color = ['green' if x>3 else 'red' for x in score]

# Create scatter plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(name, score, c=color)

# Set label for every score inside scatter plot
for i, n in enumerate(name):
    ax.annotate(n, (n,score[i]))

plt.show()
```

[image]